# Не работает темная тема в notepad++

Tags: notepad++

раньше пользовался windows, там часто работал в notepad++, а когда перешел на ubuntu, столкнулся с проблемой что темная тема частично не работает,
перепробывал все темы, и никакая из них не убирает белые полоски, а также при наведении на кнопки, они становяться белыми, навсегда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vscode твой лучший друг

Comment: мой компютер достаточно слабый, всеголишь 4гб озу, и одновременно держать открытым: VisualStudioCode, discord и бразуер, попросту невозможно

Comment: Ну это же через wine запущено, странно было бы ожидать, что все красиво будет отображаться. Тогда уж лучше какой-то легковесный и нативный для Linux редактор использовать, типа geany.

Comment: Нет, notepad++ работает без wine, скачивал из snap store

Comment: @Selasi, значит он устанавливается вместе с wine, чтобы запуститься.